# The serializer in the HttpGet method does not work correctly

Tags: c#, serialization, asp.net-core-mvc, webapi

I'm trying to write my own small API. I found an article on how to implement an API with Mongodb on ASP.NET Core MVC: [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). The problem is that when creating a GET request, the object is incorrectly serialized. As I understand it, the standard Json serializer cannot serialize objects of a custom data type.

Here is the file with the model that I am reading from the database. Everything comes from the database correctly, but when I try to send a response, a file with an empty `List<Weekday>` arrives.

```
[Serializable]
public class Group
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public Schedule schedule { get; set; }
    public Group()
    {
        groupName = "UNKNOWN";
        schedule = new Schedule();
    }
    public Group(string groupName)
    {
        this.groupName = groupName;
        schedule = new Schedule();
    }
    
}

[Serializable]
public class Schedule
{
    
    public List<Weekday> week = new List<Weekday>();
}
[Serializable]
public class Weekday
{
    public List<DaysSchedule> daysSchedules { get; set; } = new List<DaysSchedule>();
    public int dayNumber { get; set; } = 0;
}

public class DaysSchedule
{
    public List<string> dates = new List<string>();
    public List<Classes> classes = new List<Classes>();
}
public class Classes
{
    [BsonElement("ordinal")]
    public int ordinal { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("teacher")]
    public string? teacher { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("location")]
    public string location { get; set; }
    public Classes()
    {
        ordinal = 0;
        name = "UNKNOWN";
        type = "UNDEFINED";
        location = "UNDEFINED";
    }
    public Classes(int ordinal, string name, string teacher, string type, string location)
    {
        this.ordinal = ordinal;
        this.name = name;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.type = type;
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a Json file that I expect. I did not insert the entire file, as it is very large. But the main point is that the Week list contains days of the week, each of which has certain schedule options.

```
{
"Id": "63ea85829903ec2ab03720d3",
"groupName": "М3О-225Бк-21",
"schedule": {
  "week": [
    {
      "daysSchedules": [
        {
          "dates": [
            "13.02.2023",
            "13.02.2023"
          ],
          "classes": [
            {
              "ordinal": 0,
              "name": "Math",
              "teacher": "Lyahner",
              "type": "PZ",
              "location": "64"
            },
            {
              "ordinal": 1,
              "name": "Programming",
              "teacher": "Lyahner",
              "type": "LK",
              "location": "84"
            },
            {
              "ordinal": 2,
              "name": "OOP",
              "teacher": "Lyahner",
              "type": "LK",
              "location": "29"
            },
            {
              "ordinal": 3,
              "name": "OOP",
              "teacher": "Vestyak",
              "type": "LK",
              "location": "33"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dates": [
            "13.02.2023",
            "13.02.2023"
          ],
          "classes": [
            {
              "ordinal": 0,
              "name": "Phisics",
              "teacher": "Lyahner",
              "type": "LK",
              "location": "97"
            },
            {
              "ordinal": 1,
              "name": "Programming",
              "teacher": "Lyahner",
              "type": "LK",
              "location": "78"
            },
            {
              "ordinal": 2,
              "name": "Programming",
              "teacher": "Sukhno",
              "type": "PZ",
              "location": "91"
            },
            {
              "ordinal": 3,
              "name": "Programming",
              "teacher": "Sukhno",
              "type": "PZ",
              "location": "32"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dates": [
            "13.02.2023",
            "13.02.2023"
          ],
          "classes": [
            {
              "ordinal": 0,
              "name": "OOP",
              "teacher": "Vestyak",
              "type": "LK",
              "location": "93"
            },
            {
              "ordinal": 1,
              "name": "Math",
              "teacher": "Lyahner",
              "type": "PZ",
              "location": "72"
            },
            {
              "ordinal": 2,
              "name": "Math",
              "teacher": "Vestyak",
              "type": "LK",
              "location": "70"
            },
            {
              "ordinal": 3,
              "name": "Phisics",
              "teacher": "Vestyak",
              "type": "LK",
              "location": "42"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dayNumber": 0
.......................................
```

Here's what Json I get:

```
{
  "id": "63ea85829903ec2ab03720d3",
  "groupName": "М3О-225Бк-21",
  "schedule": {}
}
```

Here is the code of my Controller. Here I don't quite understand how the Http Get and Http Post attributes work. I understand that they configure routing and transfer control to a method for processing and sending a response. But where does the serialization of the Group object take place and how is it passed to the method? I tried to implement serialization explicitly by taking a string variable in the Get method and serializing the object using Newtonsoft.Json, it worked, but I don't think this option is correct and suits me. I would like to know what the problem is? And can I set custom serialization for the Group object so that I can pass and return it from methods with routing attributes?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ThreeplyWebApi.Services;
using ThreeplyWebApi.Models;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace ThreeplyWebApi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("controller")]
    public class GroupsController : ControllerBase
    {
        readonly private GroupsService _groupsService;

        public GroupsController(GroupsService schedulesService)
        {
            _groupsService = schedulesService;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<Group>> Get() => await _groupsService.GetAsync();

        [HttpGet("{groupName}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Group>> Get(string groupName)
        {
            var group = await _groupsService.GetAsync(groupName);
            if (group == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(group);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Group newGroup) 
        {
            await _groupsService.CreateAsync(newGroup);
            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { groupName = newGroup.groupName }, newGroup);

        }
    }
}
```

I also provide the code of my service for accessing the database, the methods of which are called by the controller to access the database.

```
namespace ThreeplyWebApi.Services
{

    public class GroupsService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Group> _groupsCollection;
        public GroupsService(IOptions<GroupsDatabaseSettings> groupDatabaseSettings)
        {
            var MongoClient = new MongoClient(groupDatabaseSettings.Value.ConnectionString);
            var MongoDatabase = MongoClient.GetDatabase(groupDatabaseSettings.Value.DatabaseName);
            _groupsCollection = MongoDatabase.GetCollection<Group>(groupDatabaseSettings.Value.GroupsCollectionName);
        }
        public async Task<List<Group>> GetAsync()
        {
          return await _groupsCollection.Find<Group>(_ => true).ToListAsync();
        }
        public async Task<Group> GetAsync(string groupName)
        {
           return  await _groupsCollection.Find(x => x.groupName == groupName).FirstOrDefaultAsync();   
        }
        
        public async Task CreateAsync(Group group) {
            await _groupsCollection.InsertOneAsync(group);
        }
        
        public async Task UpdateAsync(string groupName, Group updatedGroup) =>
            await _groupsCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(x => x.groupName == groupName, updatedGroup);
        public async Task RemoveAsync(string groupName) =>
            await _groupsCollection.DeleteOneAsync(x => x.groupName == groupName);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: HTTP POST requests supply additional data from the client (browser) to the server in the message body. In contrast, GET requests include all required data in the URL. "where does the serialization of the Group object take place and how is it passed to the method" It's done by Serializer. If you want to know more, you can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0). Besides,  about your  Schedule is null,  maybe you can search something about navigation properties in Mongodb.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in fact the problem was that `List<Weekday>` lacked the set and get methods. Although the field is public, it turned out that for serialization it was necessary to specify these two methods explicitly